# Making a drop down list a jQuery custom select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make my dropdown list a jQuery Mobile Custom select menu (http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/selectmenu-custom/) (http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/):

Here is what it has to say:

> To use custom menus on a specific select, just add the
>   data-native-menu="false" attribute. Alternately, this can also
>   programmatically set the select menu's nativeMenu configuration option
>   to false in a callback bound to the mobileinit event to achieve the
>   same effect. This will globally make all selects use the custom menu
>   by default. The following must be included in the page after jQuery is
>   loaded but before jQuery Mobile is loaded.

```
$(document).on( "mobileinit", function() {  
$.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false; });
```

So I first tried to add it to my server control:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlLocJobPhOpt" data-mini="true" data-native-menu="false"></asp:DropDownList>
```

I appears to be rendering just like the example:

```
<select name="ddlLocJobPhOpt" id="ddlLocJobPhOpt" data-mini="true" data-native-menu="false">
    <option value="Select" data-theme="a">Select</option>
    <option value="100101" data-theme="a">100101</option>
</select>
```

Next I tried to add the jQuery between where jQuery and jQuery mobile loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"> </script>
<script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false;
    });
</script>
<script src="Scripts/CustomScripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.js"></script>
```

Neither of them is doing anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you click on selectmenu, how does it look like?

Comment: Like a standard drop down menu.

Comment: Make sure that mobileinit event fires. Try `$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", function () { $("select").selectmenu({ nativeMenu: false }); });`.